# Azure Data Factory : Data Flow : Display a particular derived columns type

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, azure-data-factory

I am trying to determine the outgoing type of a derived column.
I am using the expression :

**toBinary(sha2(256,'my data'))** expecting a BINARY type, its target is a SNOWFLAKE BINARY(64) column.

I am getting a DF-Snowflake-InvalidDataT error from the pipeline run.

Is there a way of actually dumping out the derived type?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: You can find the type of the column in the projection -> mapping of the sink in dataflows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#field-mapping

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to determine the outgoing type of a derived column.

You can see the datatype of in the inspect tab of the derived column transformation.
Here I have added a column and used same expression.

[image]

Here is the inspect tab where you can see the datatype of all columns including the new column.

[image]

You can see the same in sink inspect also.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to examine the outputs.